# Python- facing problem in updating the dictionary keys after removing a task in a To-Do List CLI app

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm learning Python and trying to code a to-do list currently. Here is my code:

```
    msg = """
    Welcome to the To-Do List App! Choose one:
    1. Add a task.
    2. List tasks.
    3. Mark a task as done.
    4. Remove a task.
    5. Quit."""

    print(msg)
    
    
    class ToDoList:
        def __init__(self):
            self.tasks = {}  # dictionary to store tasks
            self.count = 0   # updating it, we'll get the dictionary keys
    
        def add_task(self):
            task = input("Enter task description: ")
            date = input("Enter due date (dd-mm-yyyy): ")
            self.count += 1
            self.tasks[self.count] = {"task": task, "date": date, "done": False}
            print("Task added sucessfully!")
    
        def display_tasks(self):
            print("\n--- To-Do List ---")
    
            for key, val in self.tasks.items():
                if val["done"]:
                    print(f"{key}. {val['task']} [Done].")
                else:
                    print(f"{key}. {val['task']} (Due {val['date']}).")
    
        def mark_task_done(self):
            num = int(input("Enter the task number to mark as done: "))
    
            if 1 <= num <= len(self.tasks):
                self.tasks[num]['done'] = True
                print(f"Task {num} marked as done!")
            else:
                print("Invalid key! Try again...")
    
        def remove_task(self):
            num = int(input("Enter the task number to remove: "))
    
            if 1 <= num <= len(self.tasks):
                del self.tasks[num]
                print(f"Task {num} removed successfully!")
                # self.tasks[num] = {"task": "Removed!", "date": "", "done": True}
    
                for i in range(num + 1, len(self.tasks)):
                    self.tasks[i - 1] = self.tasks.pop(i)
    
                self.count -= 1
    
            else:
                print("Invalid key! Try again...")
    
    
    def main():
        to_do_list = ToDoList()
    
        while True:
            command = input("\nEnter your choice: ").strip()
    
            if command.isdigit() and 1 <= int(command) <= 5:
                choice = int(command)
    
                match choice:
                    case 1:
                        to_do_list.add_task()
                    case 2:
                        to_do_list.display_tasks()
                    case 3:
                        to_do_list.mark_task_done()
                    case 4:
                        to_do_list.remove_task()
                    case 5:
                        print("Goodbye!")
                        break
    
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid choice!")
                continue
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

**What I want:** I am storing the tasks in a dictionary, `self.tasks` (most probably, it is dumb, but I wanted to try it!) with the dictionary keys as the task numbers. Let's say I add four tasks to the to-do list and remove the third one. After removal, I want to display the 4th task (before removal) as the new 3rd task in the to-do list. So, I must update the following dictionary keys: starting from the key following the removed key to the last key. Yes, if I delete the last task, there is no need to update any key.

**What I tried:** Kindly notice the `remove_task()` method to find what I tried.

**Currently, I'm getting the following output:**

```
Welcome to the To-Do List App! Choose one:
1. Add a task.
2. List tasks.
3. Mark a task as done.
4. Remove a task.
5. Quit.

Enter your choice: 1
Enter task description: Do 1
Enter due date (dd-mm-yyyy): 2023
Task added sucessfully!

Enter your choice: 1
Enter task description: do 2
Enter due date (dd-mm-yyyy): 2024
Task added sucessfully!

Enter your choice: 1
Enter task description: do 3
Enter due date (dd-mm-yyyy): 2000
Task added sucessfully!

Enter your choice: 1
Enter task description: do 4
Enter due date (dd-mm-yyyy): 1999
Task added sucessfully!

Enter your choice: 2

--- To-Do List ---
1. Do 1 (Due 2023).
2. do 2 (Due 2024).
3. do 3 (Due 2000).
4. do 4 (Due 1999).

Enter your choice: 4
Enter the task number to remove: 3
Task 3 removed successfully!

Enter your choice: 2

--- To-Do List ---
1. Do 1 (Due 2023).
2. do 2 (Due 2024).
4. do 4 (Due 1999).

Enter your choice: 1
Enter task description: do 5
Enter due date (dd-mm-yyyy): 2019
Task added sucessfully!

Enter your choice: 2

--- To-Do List ---
1. Do 1 (Due 2023).
2. do 2 (Due 2024).
4. do 5 (Due 2019).

Enter your choice: 5
Goodbye!
```

I must be missing something... Please give me hints to modify my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better to not use the task number as the key in the first place, so you never need to update it.  Use some other value that is actually meaningful, like the name.

Comment: @John Gordon Yes, and we should list (some sort of ordering) the tasks in a to-do list, right? How can I do that then? Thank you for responding...

Comment: Yes, a list would probably be better than a dictionary.

Comment: But interestingly, shouldn't the current logic work ?

Comment: @JohnGordon  I could try that. Maybe creating a text file would also be a better option (which I learned recently only!). I just wanted to try dictionaries. Thank you!

Comment: I have posted an updated `remove_task` , give it a try, but I cannot understand why your logic didn't work, would love to know the answer :D

Comment: @rr_goyal A dictionary will still work, but it would only allow one task with the same name (or whatever thing you chose to use as the key).

Comment: I agree with using a better approach as you suggested, but just thinking about the logic that the OP wrote, I though the remove function should have worked. Just simply thinking why the dictionary isn't being updated using OP's method.

Answer (score 1):

As [@John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon) mentioned, it is advisable to get a better key rather than task number. However, as a beginner if you want to go with the same and reach your desired outcome, you might try this -

```
def remove_task(self):
    num = int(input("Enter the task number to remove: "))

    if 1 <= num <= len(self.tasks):
        self.count -= 1
        if num != len(self.tasks):
            # Creating a list of tasks that will be updated.
            tasks_to_update = [(i, self.tasks[i+1]) for i in range(num, len(self.tasks))]
            self.tasks.update(tasks_to_update)

            # Deleting the duplicated last task.
            del self.tasks[len(self.tasks)]

        else:
            del self.tasks[num]

        print(f"Task {num} removed successfully!")


    else:
        print("Invalid key! Try again...")
```

I replace the value of the key which is to be deleted with the value of the next task. This is repeated for all the tasks with a key > key_to_be_deleted. It is similar to deleting that task. If the key at the last is to be deleted, we just use `del`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write out an answer. I was just wondering if we really need to delete the duplicated last key or if there will be any duplicates! I am referring to the line `del self.tasks[len(self.tasks)]`, because if I understood the list comprehension correctly, `i` will only go up to `len(self.tasks) - 1`, right? Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: So, in the for loop we are just replacing the current `num` with the `num+1`, this will happen till the last element. The last element won't be replaced with anything BUT it will replace the second last element. Hence, the second last and last element become equal and we delete the last element calling it as a duplicate. for `len(self.tasks) - 1`, i think it might replace till 2nd last element and the same logic wont work.

Comment: I was working with an example: let's say we have 4 tasks, and we delete the 3rd one (the program works fine as of now!) and then add a new task... it gets a task number of 5 instead of 4. Please check the same.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to add the statement `self.count-=1` Have made the changes, hope this helped you!

Comment: It surely did... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens in your `remove_task` function because you have already deleted the task before you rearrange your `dict`, so when you delete the task at the beginning of the function, your tasks `dict` now includes only 3 tasks inside of it, and there is a problem with your `range` function, the range function doesn't include the upper bound as an element of the resulting range, so you have to add 1.

Here is the proper solution for your issue:

```py
    def remove_task(self):
        num = int(input("Enter the task number to remove: "))
        if num == len(self.tasks):
            del self.tasks[num]
        elif 1 <= num < len(self.tasks):
            for i in range(num + 1, len(self.tasks)+1):
                self.tasks[i - 1] = self.tasks.pop(i)

            self.count -= 1
            print(f"Task {num} removed successfully!")

        else:
            print("Invalid key! Try again...")
```

Comment: Thank you... Also, I have a doubt: will the last task get deleted now (or, while we try to delete the last task, we will actually be deleting the second last task?) I should try it out...

Comment: I think you have to check if it is the last task you just delete it without rearrange the dict

Comment: I edited the code for considering the last task, not tested yet , but this is the logic

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I made some similar changes. According to me, we should make the following changes: 
```if 1 <= num <= len(self.tasks):
            if num == len(self.tasks):
                del self.tasks[num]
            else:
                for i in range(num + 1, len(self.tasks) + 1):
                    self.tasks[i - 1] = self.tasks.pop(i)

            self.count -= 1
            print(f"Task {num} removed successfully!")
        else:
            print("Invalid task number! Try again...")```

The formatting is horrible. Hope you will get it.

Comment: Anyway, it works as I expected it to. Thank you so much for pointing out my mistake in the first place. Kindly check it out and I would love to accept your answer.